# NodeJS Clustering and Worker Threads

Tags: node.js

I am doing some research for a home project and I'm looking into the Cluster Module and Worker Threads.

I know the difference between Cluster and Worker Threads.

My question is:

In NodeJS is it possible to use Clustering and Worker Threads at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're thinking of the [worker threads module](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) when you're referring to "worker threads". I'm making a clear distinction since NodeJS runtime comes with 4 worker threads by default. *cluster* (module) and *worker_threads* shouldn't have any problems working in parallel as clustering provides you with **multiple independent NodeJS instances**, as in, **multiple NodeJS processes** which have their own threads as stated before. Spawning more worker threads using the above mentioned `worker_threads` module spawns more **threads** which aren't independent (they can and do share memory), which can be good if you're doing some crunching, but they all run under a single Node process.
Processes can communicate using IPC, and Node worker threads can talk using the `MessagePort` class from the same module.

Therefore, yes, you can do that and my best guess is that, on the top of the "supervision tree" of sorts you spawn a couple of Node *processes* (using the `cluster` module) to distribute the load if you have them acting as servers (no clue about your use case), and then for each process you can use the `worker_threads` module to spawn additional threads if needed (to speed up some heavy processing etc).

Comment: Straight from node doc: "Workers (threads) are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations. They do not help much with I/O-intensive work. The Node.js built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers can be." Don't use worker threads for io.